# Cache without 'on' subscription

Tags: javascript, firebase

Is it possible to tell firebase to cache a path without having a 'on' subscription?

Currently I'm doing the following which is both inefficient, space waste and ugly:

```
const ref = new Firebase(someUrl)

app.get('slow/:id', (req, res) => {
  ref.child(id).on('value', snapshot => res.send(snapshot.val()))
})

const cache = {}

ref.on('child_added', snapshot => cache[snapshot.key()] = snapshot.val())
ref.on('child_changed', snapshot => cache[snapshot.key()] = snapshot.val())
ref.on('child_removed', snapshot => delete cache[snapshot.key()])

app.get('fast_wasteful_ugly/:id', (req, res) => {
  const val = cache[req.params.id]

  if (val !== undefined)
    res.send(val)
  else
    ref.child(req.params.id).once('value', snapshot => res.send(snapshot.val()))
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is *no* - there is currently no means of telling Firebase to cache the data at a path without attaching an event listener.

That said, give some thought to which problem(s) you're trying to solve. If you'd like to get synchronous access to data stored in Firebase, then the approach that you mentioned above is currently the best way to do it.

However, if you'd simply like to avoid a network roundtrip for retrieving data, than attaching a single Firebase event listener where you'd like to maintain caching might solve your issue. In that case, you'd pass a no-op block when attaching the listener and use `ref.once('value', ...)` throughout your code. By attaching the initial listener with the no-op block, all of your subsequence calls to `ref.once(...)` would use the local cache and not need to hit the network.

Comment: Ok. No-op handler it is. Would be nice to have a bit more pragmatic way to do it.